# All links in Google Chrome become linkclk.com/adfly/goto.php?i=

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, links

For some unknown reason, all the link in Google Chrome become `linkclk.com/adfly/goto.php?i=...`

I've checked Chrome Extension but none are concerned. What are the cause ?

Comment: Check your PC for malware with Malwarebytes or something like that.

Comment: @gronostaj how can malware inject Chrome ?

Comment: Well, there are hundreds of ways to do it. The easiest one would be to run a local proxy and use it to replace links.

Comment: @gronostaj I run a full scan but the problem still exists

Comment: some extension is still causing that. Which extensions are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It was because of Selection Link extension in Google Chrome.
Here is [how to remove it](http://botcrawl.com/how-to-remove-selectionlinks/)